# Magento 2.4 - Express Checkout - Shipping Address Error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, magento2

A fresh install Magento 2.4.x + theme, but having some issue related to express checkout, as seen from below picture on red-box area.

[image]

The form has missing some elements, like firstname, lastname etc.
When I compare things around, it should have it. Do I miss some setup?

Also, when I check on console, I've seen some javascript error that I'm not familiar with, as below

*edit - one additional error that I forgot to add

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "afterRender: function(){return oscAddress.fieldAfterRender(element.dataScope) }"
Message: oscAddress is not defined
```

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function(){return { data:elems,as:'element'} }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return element.visible() }"
Message: Unable to process binding "ifnot: function(){return (element.input_type =='checkbox'|| element.input_type =='radio') }"
Message: Unable to process binding "template: function(){return $parent.fieldTemplate }"
Message: Unable to process binding "afterRender: function(){return oscAddress.fieldAfterRender(element.dataScope) }"
Message: oscAddress is not defined
```

I'm not really familiar with front-end stack on Magento, so I don't know what I need to do.

Any suggestion? Do I miss some server / code setup? or maybe Admin setup?
I already tried to refresh cache etc, but the problem still remains.
Also, I already change to **Luma** / default theme, but the problem still persist. So, I'm wondering if there's something that I missed.

PS - I already fulfill the requirements to install Magento, like, PHP version, elasticsearch version, etc, as-per documentation. So, I'm wondering if there's something that I missed out.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may be possible there is another one page checkout plugin that creates a conflict
Just disable "One Page Checkout" from settings

Stores > Saltes > One Page Checkout

Comment: thanks for trying to help! I appreciate it. And yes, there was an issue on the themes back theme, as I check on their theme developers. Cheers! :)